# unable to start or stop vsftpd

Tags: vsftpd

When I try to start vsftpd it fails.

When running `netstat -anp | grep :21` I get the following result:

```
tcp 0 0 :::21 :::* LIST EN 4046/proftpd
```

What can I do to make sure that vsftpd starts and stops correctly?

Comment: Can you please edit the question?  Just dumping your config file into the question doesn't help much (and given previous interaction it's probably not even related).  Instead describe what you are seeing, what you want to see, and what you've tried to get from one to the other.  Please read http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, given previous discussion, you probably just need to stop `proftp` and then you'll be able to start `vsftpd`, but you'll need to adjust your service definitions to make sure `proftpd` doesn't try to start next time

Answer (score 3):

That line from `netstat` means you already have an ftp server running.  You could either stop that one or have `vsftpd` run on another port.  Most likely you want the former.

```
service proftpd stop
service vsftpd start
```

should work (depending on your OS) or

```
/etc/init.d/proftpd stop
/etc/init.d/vsftpd start
```

or

```
systemctl stop proftpd
systemctl start vsftpd
```

Then you'll want to make sure that this change is persistent with something like

```
chkconfig proftpd off
chkconfig vsftpd on
```

or

```
systemctl disable proftpd
systemctl enable vsftpd
```

or something similar to one of those.  If you tell us the platform we can help more specifically.

Comment: CentOS 6 64bit Game-Template

Comment: Then the `service`/`chkconfig` options should work for you

Comment: And what about that ftp_psa missing? This service/chkconfig worked fine...

Comment: What is ftp_psa?  I'm not familiar with it.  The only reference I found was to running an ftp server under `xinetd` which doesn't really apply to this way of doing it, so perhaps it's not necessary?

Comment: I really don`t know. I`m trying to configure swift panel with cs 1.6. And I`m reading a lot of forums on how to, and on every step on a different forum I step on some kind of a problem... Sorry about my English... I`m from Serbia. Thank u 4 ur help anyway...